# How can I convert a vector<uint8_t> into an unsigned char*

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, reinterpret-cast

I have a `const vector<uint8_t>>`, and I need to pass it to a function that takes a `const unsigned char*`. The two types are the same size, etc., so I'm guessing that there is an good way to coerce the types here. What's the idiomatic way of handling this type of problem?

My first instinct is to use [reinterpret_cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b.aspx), but after the cast the data isn't the same. Here is my code:

```
shared_ptr<const vector<uint8_t>> data = operation.getData();
const unsigned char* data2 = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&data);
myFunction(data2, data->size());
```

Chances are I've confused a pointer for a value here, but maybe my entire approach is incorrect.

Comment: Or rather: `data->data()`

Comment: `vector::data()` returns a pointer to the actual data within the vector.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Why? Why? I must be going crazy. How on earth did `operator->` not come to mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` is almost never the right solution, unless you know *exactly* what you’re doing, and even then usually not.

In your case, you just want a pointer to the contiguous data storage inside the vector (but **not** the vector itself, as you’ve noticed! That stores other data as well, such as the size & capacity). That’s easy enough, it’s the pointer of the first element of the data:

```
&vector[0]
```

So your code would look as follows:

```
myFunction(&(*data)[0], data->size());
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. The note about reinterpret_cast is also memorable; I will keep it far from me until I've figured out the rest of the tools that I've been cutting my hands on :)

Comment: It is also possible to use, and sometimes more readable, to use `std::vector::front()`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front

Answer (score 1):

Just use `vector<unsigned char>` to begin with. On all platforms, `unsigned char` will have at least 8 bits. On platforms that have an 8-bit unsigned integral type, `uint8_t` will be a synonym for `unsigned char`; on platforms that do not have an 8-bit unsigned integral type, `uint8_t` will not exist, but `unsigned char` will.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for "`uint8_t` will be a synonym for `unsigned char`"? Couldn't it also be a typedef for `char` or even for an extended unsigned integer type?

Comment: @DyP - you're right, `uint8_t` could be a synonym for `char` with a compiler that makes `char` `unsigned`. Unless your code **requires** an **exact** 8 bit type, don't use `uint8_t`. That's a rather rare requirement.